# Setting project localization date

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

How can I setup my ASP.net MVC 4 project to use my country datetime, because I am hosting my app on the cloud - apphabour?

I am now using `Datetime.Now()` to retrieve the latest app?

Answer (score 0):

Datetime.now returns the current time and time zone defined by the settings for the server clock or the domain time service for the ad controller. Normally dates stored in a database ( or code ) are returned as UFC date time so that web clients /windows clients can convert utc time to local time defined by the settings on each workstation.